# Can't bind to property since it isn't a known property of element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a dynamic label to my `ion-fab-button` element but I can't seem to get it to work because I need to be able to supply the value from a variable but I am unable to bind to the property.  I've tried the following but see the error:

> Error: Template parse errors:  Can't bind to 'desc' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-fab-button'.

```
<ion-fab-button
  color="success"
  [disabled]="true"
  desc="Already Sent Scale: {{ variable }}"
  class="labelOnRight"
>
  <i class="fa fa-presentation fs-24"></i>
</ion-fab-button>
```

In my css I use the `desc` to create a label:

```
ion-fab-button.labelOnRight[desc]::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(desc);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 55px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  padding: 5px 9px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?  Everything works when the `desc` attribute is hard coded, but not when it's dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use data attributes : `<ion-fab-button [attr.data-desc]></ion-fab-button>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the attribute. I am on the phone so cant test but let me know if it works.

Try  [attr.desc]=" 'Already sent scale' + variable"